# meta description не отображается в результатах поиска в Яндекс

Tags: seo, поисковые-системы, meta, яндекс-поиск

Сутки назад добавил на сайт meta-тег description `<meta name="description" content="мой текст">`, но в Яндексе в описании сайта почему-то выводится список страниц сайта, а не моё описание. Какая может быть причина?

Comment: Попробуйте отправить сайт на повторную индексацию Яндексу. Он не следит за изменениями, а загружает данные, которые собрал робот, когда последний раз посещал ваш сайт.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно пройти эту повторную индексацию? В Яндекс.Вебмастере не могу найти, где это можно сделать.

Comment: В личном кабинете "Индексирование" -> "Переобход страниц"